# nvm or npm, installing packages

Tags: node.js, npm, nvm

I go to ~/tmp

when I do `npm install eslint`

- on one system

it's installed `~/.nvm/versions/node/v10.17.0/lib/node_modules/eslint`
(and it's found via `which eslint` because `~/.nvm/..` is included in my `PATH`)

- on another system
  it's installed `~/tmp/node_modules/eslint` where I'm running the `npm install` command

Both systems have nvm, and both have nvm setup script in the zshrc file

```
export NVM_DIR="/Users/eugenekim/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends, `nvm` stands for node version manager. This means you can have multiple versions of node on you device at the same time. `npm` stands for *Node package manager*. `npm` comes with `Node.js` and allows you to install Javascript packages. So to answer your question, you should use `npm` UNLESS you want a SEPARATE version of `Node.js` for your package, which I don't think you need.